# How to replace single quotes string with literal if it contains escaped single quotes?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

I need to escape all single quotes strings with literals and I am using the following regular expression:

```
'[^']*'
```

It is working fine, except when I have escaped single quotes in the string that must be replaced itself. For example, for the following string:

```
[COMPUTE:{IIF([Client Name] LIKE '%Happy%', 'Happy\'s', 'Other\'s Jr.')}]
```

I have these matches:

```
%Happy%
Happy\
, 
s Jr.
```

I can replace the `\'` with some other sequence of characters (for example `internal_value`) and than to perform the string replacement, but it will be more clearer if I can do this with the regular expression instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a negative look behind.  Basically just use a lazy match to anything `.*?` then you can put a negative look behind for a backslash `(?<!\\)` before the end single quote.

```
var reg = new Regex(@"'.*?(?<!\\)'");

foreach(Match m in reg.Matches(@"[COMPUTE:{IIF([Client Name] LIKE '%Happy%', 'Happy\'s', 'Other\'s Jr.')}]"))
    Console.WriteLine(m);
```

outputs

> '%Happy%'
>
> 'Happy\'s'
>
> 'Other\'s Jr.'

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
'((?:[^'\\]+|\\.)*)'
```

(*modified a bit from the bible of regex :- Mastering Regular expression*)

**[regexstorm demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%27((%3F%3A%5B%5E%27%5C%5C%5D%2B%7C%5C%5C.)*)%27&i=%5BCOMPUTE%3A%7BIIF(%5BClient%20Name%5D%20LIKE%20%27%25Happy%25%27%2C%20%27Happy%5C%27s%27%2C%20%27Other%5C%27s%20Jr.%27)%7D%5D)**